# QGIS - not saving changes in shapefile after merging two polygons

Tags: qgis

[image]I have polygon shapefile. Two of the polygons needed to be merged to create one record (with two polys). I carried this out in QGIS by selecting the two polys to be merged and selecting the 'merge selected features' tool. I chose the record to pick the attributes from and clicked Apply. This worked. But when I try to save the changes I get the message attached. It seems to be suggesting that there is a geometry type that shouldn't be in there. But it is all polygons. And if I were to delete that merged polygon the layer can be saved. So, what is stopping this shapefile being saved?

Comment: You can't create one record with two polygons, You can create one record with one multipolygon. Without an attached message, it's difficult to proceed.

Comment: Hi @KadirŞahbaz, Please see image in the post for the error message received. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Vince. Please see image in the post. Thanks.

Comment: The shapefile specification says that all 2D polygons are one type. QGIS has additional rules, classifying them as polygon or multipolygon. You need to define the layer as supporting multipolygons in order to save a multi-part polygon to shapefile.

Comment: Could you also share layer information from layer properties like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QffXd.png)? This is strange because shapefiles allow multipolygon for polygon type.

Comment: I'd run a Check or if needed Fix Geometry tool just to make sure that isn't an issue.